# Displaying multiple rows in multiple textboxes

Tags: sql, vb.net, sqldatareader

I have a SQL Database table with multiple rows. I want to get the data from the rows based on the ID of that row and then present it in a certain textbox. I've got it working with Access 2013, but i've recently decided to move it to SQL.

I get an error

> "There is already an open Datareader associated with this command"

Before i show you the code, it's pretty simplistic. I kind of "made" it work with access 2013, but SQL doesn't like it. The way the APP works it is paramount to have the data displayed in textboxes to make it easier to amend the data whilst being able to tab to the next box efficiently. That's why i haven't used Gridview. well, i have but that is for an asset register which is fine.

The code:

```
Try
        conn.Open()
        '***************** Populate Textboxes based on ID 1 row of PrinterDetails ***************** '
        Dim sql1 As String
        sql1 = "select * from PrinterDetails where ID=1"
        cmd = New SQLCommand(sql1, conn)
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While reader.Read
            '' Convert to string to prevent DBNULL errors
            SNAME1.Text = reader.Item("SiteName").ToString
            MAKE1.Text = reader.Item("Make").ToString
            MODEL1.Text = reader.Item("Model").ToString
            PRINTERIP1.Text = reader.Item("PrinterIP").ToString
            PSERVER1.Text = reader.Item("Server").ToString
            SHARE1.Text = reader.Item("Share").ToString
            LOC1.Text = reader.Item("Location").ToString
            UN1.Text = reader.Item("Username").ToString
            PASS1.Text = reader.Item("Password").ToString
            SUPPORT1.Text = reader.Item("Support").ToString
        End While
        '***************** Populate Textboxes based on ID 2 row of PrinterDetails ***************** '
        Dim sql2 As String
        sql2 = "select * from PrinterDetails where ID=2"
        cmd = New SQLCommand(sql2, conn)
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While reader.Read
            '' Convert to string to prevent DBNULL errors
            SNAME2.Text = reader.Item("SiteName").ToString
            MAKE2.Text = reader.Item("Make").ToString
            MODEL2.Text = reader.Item("Model").ToString
            PRINTERIP2.Text = reader.Item("PrinterIP").ToString
            PSERVER2.Text = reader.Item("Server").ToString
            SHARE2.Text = reader.Item("Share").ToString
            LOC2.Text = reader.Item("Location").ToString
            UN2.Text = reader.Item("Username").ToString
            PASS2.Text = reader.Item("Password").ToString
            SUPPORT2.Text = reader.Item("Support").ToString
        End While
```

I've tried closing the connection and re-opening but that doesn't work.

Comment: close the Reader not the connection, better yet put it in a Using block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why such a bizarre query and code; your SQL query can simply be like below using a `IN` operator

```
select * from PrinterDetails where ID in (1,2);
```

BTW, for your issue check [This MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) specifically the *Remarks* section. In essence, you will need to close the already opened reader.

Comment: Hi Rahul. Thanks for the prompt reply. 

I did try closing the reader but it turns out i just put it before the while loop finished not after.. whoops!

In regards to using your query; could you give me an example of how you'd incorporate that into textboxes as i can't get it to work.

I appreciate all your help.